# I want to delete the specific objects from s3 bucket after 7 days expiry using cloud formation scripts

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to delete the specific objects from s3 bucket after 7 days, using cloud formation scripts

Comment: What is stopping you? What you have tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by "specific objects"? Or do you mean _all objects_ that are more than 7 days old? Do you know about [Object Lifecycle Management - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html)?

Comment: Hi John, specific objects means in that bucket lot of files are there, and I want to delete the file using their date and either prefix(name)

Comment: I konw about s3 bucket little bit but not more. And don't know about object lifecycle management